# Failed Retrieving Guava Libs from Maven

Tags: maven, clojure, guava, mahout, leiningen

I am using leiningin to create and compile the first example from Mahout in Action on recommender systems.  I am trying to build the dependencies, but Guava is failing.  How can I fix this?

```
$ lein deps
Retrieving com/google/guava/guava/r03/guava-r03.pom from central
Retrieving com/google/guava/guava/r03/guava-r03.pom from central
Could not transfer artifact com.google.guava:guava:pom:r03 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/):      
Checksum validation failed, expected 1cbd6fab2460050ff7147b6d8536f39c8f535067 but is    
7a37041386ee39a1fbb3efd3c4c6932809cb5887
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
```

My project.clj file:

```
(defproject recommend "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Recommendation examples from Mahout in Action"
  :dependencies [
    [org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
    [org.apache.mahout/mahout-core "0.5"]
    [org.apache.mahout/mahout-math "0.5"]
    [org.apache.mahout/mahout-utils "0.5"]]
  :main recommend.core)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like the error you would get if the download failed or you got the wrong data. I have had this happen when at a coffee shop where I ran lein deps before signing into the local networks web capture login page.

If the problem persists first try running

```
lein clean && lein deps
```

then if you still have troubles try moving your local maven repo (~/.m2/repository/) out of the way and try again.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I'll keep that in mind.  In this case it happend to be a maven repo issue https://getsatisfaction.com/sonatype/topics/guava_artifacts_broken